# How convert between different kinds of multidimensional arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

I'm migrating from python/numpy to julia. I'm really confused by Julia's multidimensional arrays and it feels like there is some additional level of  complexity / hassle (in comparison to numpy).

There is distinction between 1)row-vectros 2)column-vectors, 3)multidimensional arrays and 4)nested arrays (=Arrays of arrays). That would be all fine (perhaps useful for performance optimization), assuming there is simple way how to convert between them. But I cannot figure out how to do it.

**Simple example:** 
I just try to generate 2D rectangular grid of points and plot them

```
ps = [ [ix*0.1 iy*0.1] for ix=1:10, iy=1:10 ]
# 10×10 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}:
# Oh, this is nested array? I wand just simple 3D array 10x10x2

scatter( ps[:,:,1], ps[:,:,2], markersize = 2, markerstrokewidth = 0, aspect_ratio=:equal )
# ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 10×10 Array{Array{Float64,2},2} at index [Base.Slice(Base.OneTo(10)), Base.Slice(Base.OneTo(10)), 2]

sh = size(ps)
# (10,10)

ps = reshape( ps, ( sh[1]*sh[2],2) )
# ERROR: DimensionMismatch("new dimensions (100, 2) must be consistent with  array size 100")
# Oh dear :(

ps = reshape( ps, ( sh[1]*sh[2],:) )
# 100×1 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}

xs = ps[:,1]
# 100-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}
# ??? WTF? ... this arrays looks like whole 'ps' 
ys = ps[:,2] 
# ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 100×1 Array{Array{Float64,2},2} at index [Base.Slice(Base.OneTo(100)), 2]

xs = ps[:][1]
# 1×2 Array{Float64,2}: 
#  0.1  0.1
#  But I want all xs  (ps[:,1]), not (ps[1,:]) 

# Let's try some broadcasting
xs = ps.[1]
# ERROR: syntax: invalid syntax "ps.[1]"
xs = .ps[1]
# ERROR: syntax: invalid identifier name "."


# Perhaps transpose will help?
ps_ = ps'   #' stackoverflow syntax highlighting for Julia is broken ?
# 1×100 LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float64,Array{Float64,2}},Array{Array{Float64,2},2}}:
# OMG! ... That is even worse

scatter( ps[:,1], ps[:,2], markersize = 2, markerstrokewidth = 0, aspect_ratio=:equal )
# Nope
```

OK this somehow works. But still I need to figure out how to convert between the different shapes of arrays above

```
using Plots
ps = [ [ix*0.1 iy*0.1] for ix=1:10, iy=1:10 ]
ps = vcat(ps...)
xs = ps[:,1]
ys = ps[:,2]
scatter( xs, ys, markersize = 2, markerstrokewidth = 0, aspect_ratio=:equal )
```

EDIT:

Maybe it could be good to list some tutorials where I was searching the answer before I asked:

- https://juliadocs.github.io/Julia-Cheat-Sheet/
- https://cheatsheets.quantecon.org/
- https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/julia/
- https://juliabyexample.helpmanual.io/
- https://julia.guide/broadcasting

Comment: If you want to broadcast indexing `arr.[index]` doesn't work, but `getindex.(arr, index)` does. The square brackets are just syntactic sugar for a `getindex` call.

Comment: There aren't any row vectors or column vectors. It's just 1d arrays, 2d arrays, 3d arrays etc. And no special `nested arrays'. It's just that arrays could have any sort of members, *including* other arrays. It is, frankly, a _lot_ simpler, more general, and consistent than Python/numpy.

Comment: DNF >   column vs. row does matter a lot when using broadcasting. I was following this tutorial to create 2D grid of points ( https://julia.guide/broadcasting ) and it (like `@. floor(Int, sqrt(a) + sqrt(b))`) was not working until I realized it does matter whether I write there `[2 3 4 5]` or `[2, 3, 4, 5]`. And comprehension like `[ [ix*0.1 iy*0.1] for ix=1:10, iy=1:10 ]` always produce column vector.

Comment: What I mean, is that there are no row vector or column vector types among those that you are working with, and no special 'nested arrays'. It's just 1D arrays, 2D arrays, etc. What you call row vectors and column vectors are just 2D arrays that happen to have shape 1xN or Nx1. So it seems strange to say that it's complicated because of the distinctions you enumerate, when those distinctions aren't real (except of course that 2D and higher-D arrays are different).

Comment: As for your latest example, `[2 3 4 5]` creates a 2D array, while `[2, 3, 4, 5]` creates a 1D array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julia works in column-major fashion, so the basic vector is a column vector.
To convert a column vector to a row vector, use `permutedims(colvec)`.
To convert a row vector to a column vector, use `permutedims(rowvec)`.

```
julia> colvec = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> rowvec = permutedims(colvec)
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3

julia> permutedims(rowvec)
3×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
 2
 3
```

To convert a matrix (or any 2-dimensional array) to a column vector, use `vec`.  Because Julia stores 2-dimensional arrays by column, this will traverse each column in turn. Note that 2D array dimensions are shown as `<rows>x<cols> Array{<type>,2}`.

```
julia> matrix = [1 4 
                 2 5 
                 3 6]
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6  

julia> colvec = vec(matrix)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

To convert that `colvec` back to the original array requires knowing the dimensions of that that original array. `ndims(x)` counts the dimensions of x and `size(x)` gives the number of elements in each dimension of x.

```
julia> reshape(colvec, size(matrix))
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6
```

You can transpose the entries with `permutedims(matrix)`.

```
julia> matrix
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6

julia> permutedims(matrix)
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
```

The same principles apply to higher dimensional arrays.

```
array = reshape(collect(1:12), (3, 2, 2))
3×2×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6

[:, :, 2] =
 7  10
 8  11
 9  12

julia> vec(array)
12-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
 11
 12
```

For working with nested arrays, I suggest using [RecursiveArrayTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/RecursiveArrayTools.jl%60).

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a lot in the code above, but just focusing on your point of departure and the intended outcome:

> Why nested array?

Your comprehension creates the array `[ix*0.1 iy*0.1]` for every combination of 
`ix` and `iy`, so I would argue you explicitly asked for it.

There are probably some whizzy ways to either do this with a fancy comprehension or somehow flatten the nested array, but in cases like this one I like to be explicit about what I'm trying to achieve:

```
ps = zeros(10,10,2) # 10x10x2 Array{Float64,3}
for ix = 1:10, iy = 1:10
        ps[ix, iy, :] = [ix*0.1 iy*0.1]
end
```

If it's about having a one-liner you can consider creating both 10x10 arrays in comprehensions and then concatenating those along a third dimension:

```
ps = cat([ix*0.1 for ix=1:10, iy=1:10], [iy*0.1 for ix=1:10, iy=1:10], dims = 3)
```

Comment: ok, thanks, but since this is kind of things I will be writing thousand-times in every single script I'm looking for most concise one-liners or idioms.

Answer (score 0):

Others have have given replies that help solve your problem, so I'd rather just go through your example and try to explain what is going on. You seem pretty frustrated, which is not uncommon when learning a new language, but most of your complaints seem to be because Julia is being consistent.

```
ps = [ [ix*0.1 iy*0.1] for ix=1:10, iy=1:10 ]
# 10×10 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}:
# Oh, this is nested array? I wand just simple 3D array 10x10x2
```

Here you are creating a 10x10 array, where each element is a 1x2 matrix. That's what you are asking for, it's not Julia being difficult or obscure, it's just being consistent and straightforward.

```
scatter( ps[:,:,1], ps[:,:,2], markersize = 2, markerstrokewidth = 0, aspect_ratio=:equal )
# ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 10×10 Array{Array{Float64,2},2} at index [Base.Slice(Base.OneTo(10)), Base.Slice(Base.OneTo(10)), 2]
```

You have a 2D array, so you cannot index into it with 3 indices.

```
sh = size(ps)
# (10,10)

ps = reshape( ps, ( sh[1]*sh[2],2) )
# ERROR: DimensionMismatch("new dimensions (100, 2) must be consistent with  array size 100")
# Oh dear :(
```

You have a 10x10 array and try to reshape it into a 100x2 array. The new array would have 200 elements, which is twice as much as the original, so this cannot work.

```
ps = reshape( ps, ( sh[1]*sh[2],:) )
# 100×1 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}
```

Here you reshape it into a 100x1 array, that's fine.

```
xs = ps[:,1]
# 100-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}
# ??? WTF? ... this arrays looks like whole 'ps'
```

And now you are asking for the first (and only) column of the new, reshaped `ps`. So, naturally, you get all the data. Notice that `xs` is now a 1D array, not a 100x1 2D array.

```
ys = ps[:,2] 
# ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 100×1 Array{Array{Float64,2},2} at index [Base.Slice(Base.OneTo(100)), 2]
```

You are asking for the second column of a 100x1 array.

```
xs = ps[:][1]
# 1×2 Array{Float64,2}: 
#  0.1  0.1
#  But I want all xs  (ps[:,1]), not (ps[1,:])
```

`ps[:]` turns `ps` into 1D vector with 100 elements, and then you ask for the first element of that. Seems to me to be expected behaviour.

```
# Let's try some broadcasting
xs = ps.[1]
# ERROR: syntax: invalid syntax "ps.[1]"
```

Yes, this doesn't work, and it's not unreasonable to expect that it might, but this is a possible future feature. Perhaps you are looking for `first.(ps)`, which reads the first element from each element of `ps`. Similarly, `last.(ps)` reads the last element from each element of `ps`.

```
xs = .ps[1]
# ERROR: syntax: invalid identifier name "."
```

This is not valid syntax. The dot syntax only works on functions and operators.

```
# Perhaps transpose will help?
ps_ = ps'   #' stackoverflow syntax highlighting for Julia is broken ?
# 1×100 LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float64,Array{Float64,2}},Array{Array{Float64,2},2}}:
# OMG! ... That is even worse
```

Not sure what you want to happen here. Transpose returns a lazy datatype for performance reasons. It's pretty neat.

```
scatter( ps[:,1], ps[:,2], markersize = 2, markerstrokewidth = 0, aspect_ratio=:equal )
# Nope
```

As far as I recall, you have changed `ps` into a 100x1 array, so `ps[:,2]` cannot work.

Comment: DNF - no I was not frustrated :) Sorry that the comments seems like that. I just wanted to make the text more vivid, like a cartoon. What I wanted to express is that this seemingly simple operation is not so straightforward using all the tools you normally encounter in tutorials/cheatsheets. I understand the difference between 10x10x2 array and 10x10 array of 2x1 arrays. Some convenient feature beside `arr.[i]` could be e.g. `reshape( ps, ( sh[1]*sh[2],2), deep=True )` which would unpack/repack the nested array.